# How to run a command in background for a command that have args

Tags: php, linux, bash, command-line, phantomjs

I am trying to execute a command in PHP to run in the background so that the PHP script does not have to wait for the script to finish. I am trying to use this:

```
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid COMMAND_HERE > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
```

Unfortunately, my command takes arguments and `/dev/null 2>&1 &` does not work I guess instead it goes in system args of my phantomjs.

```
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid cd /var/www/html/smartgood/'.$i.' && phantomjs dump2.js '.date('d').' '.date('m').' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
```

where `date('d').' '.date('m')` are the args I need to run the script with.

Any idea how to fix it or if there is another way to run that line in PHP without having to wait for my phantomjs script to finish?

Comment: try to add /dev/null 2>&1 & after double quotes, not inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two commands in there, so only the second one is being redirected to /dev/null. To keep things simple and maintainable, I would move all these commands to a separate bash file and run that.

Something like this (syntax needs to be checked):

**/path/to/script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
exec nohup setsid cd /var/www/html/smartgood/$1
phantomjs dump2.js $2 $3
```

Then run it with:

```
exec('bash -c /path/to/script.sh ' . $i .' ' .date('d').' '.date('m') . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
```

Comment: I am not sure why it worked when it was inside a bash file as it should be same syntax anyways. but that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this neat function I wrote a while ago.  It has cross platform support as well so will work on linux and windows

```
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
    }
}
```

Just pass you node command into `execInBackground` and watch it work :)

Comment: Doesn't work. I already tried adding " > /dev/null &" and it didn't work

Comment: as I said. the problem is my command itself have args so any linux system args you put after "Phantomjs" command will just be used as phantomjs args not linux system args. or that's what I think at least.

Comment: I use this command myself to run node tasks.  I believe the node command I run is `node main.js` and it works